# Angular 2 proper use of authentication service

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, passport.js

I am building web application using `NodeJS` for the server-side and `Angular 2` for the client-side.

In the application I'm using `ADFS` to authenticate users.

The user browses to the website and automatically redirected to the `ADFS` authentication server. After the user completes the authentication, he redirects back to my application and I get the user data from the `ADFS` server.

I used `passport-saml` package to implement the authentication and it works fine.
The user is now stored at `req.user`.

Now I need to use user's data on the client side.

After a little research, I found that passing user's data from server to client can be as simple as :

```
router.get('/user/current', AuthMiddleware.requireLogin, (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    return res.json(req.user);
});
```

This works as well.

Now for the client-side:
I've created a service to fetch the authenticated user :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private authUrl = 'http://localhost/api/user/current';
    private currentUser: User;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.getUser().subscribe(user => {
            this.currentUser = user;
        });
    }

    getUser(): Observable<User> {
        return this.http.get(this.authUrl)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error'));
    }

    isAuthenticated(): boolean {
        return !!this.currentUser;
    }
}
```

So the `getUser` method returns an `Observable` with my user and I can use it in my client-side.

But my question is :

Should I inject the `AuthService` to each component which uses the authenticated user?
And if so, should I call `getUser` each time and wait for the `Observable` to return user's data, or should I use public parameter for the authenticated user?
(for example making the `currentUser` parameter `public` in the `AuthService` and then just use `authService.currentUser`?)

Comment: were you ever able to get this to work? if so can you share your soln?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inject the `AuthService` into each component. What you want to do instead is guard the various routes in your application from activation unless a user has been authenticated. You must implement an `AuthGuard` that will have the `AuthService` injected.

Check out https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html (search the page for "GUARD THE ADMIN FEATURE") for more information.

Comment: I do have guards in my application, but guard only protects your routes and this is not what I am looking for. As I mentioned in the question, I need to get user's data in the component itself and not only to protect routes. For example, user model includes permissions and I want to display what permissions it has.

Comment: Understood. Injecting the AuthService into each component that needs access to it then is one way to go. Alternatively, you could create an abstract base component that handles the retrieval of permission information from the AuthService. Any component that requires this information can then inherit from the base component.